error for browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*" how can Fix the error
enter image description here
i download nap and browser-sync but the The same problem
browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*"
this is my error
browser-sync : File C:\Users\Shooo_rkmg90n\AppData\Roaming\npm\browser-sync.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*"

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess





............................................................................................................................................................
